# Flex row wrap contains items with different dynamic height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to code a designs that I got from a Designer. This is how it should look.
[image]

I did it in that way:

HTML

```
<div className={$.container}>
    <section className={$.box1}>Box1</section>

    <section className={$.box2}>Box2</section>

    <section className={$.box3}>Box3 can extend</section>

    <section className={$.box4}>Box4 can extend </section>

    <section className={$.box5}>Box5</section>

    <section className={$.box6}>Box6</section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;

    @include laptop-and-larger {
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}

.box1 {
    @include laptop-and-larger {
        flex-basis: 60%;
        order: 1;
    }
}

.box2 {
    @include phone-only {
        display: none;
    }

    @include laptop-and-larger {
        flex-basis: 40%;
        max-width: px(375);
        order: 2;
    }
}

.box3 {
    @include laptop-and-larger {
        flex-basis: 40%;
        max-width: px(375);
        order: 4;
    }
}

.box4 {
    @include laptop-and-larger {
        flex-basis: 60%;
        order: 3;
    }
}

.box5 {
    @include laptop-and-larger {
        flex-basis: 40%;
        max-width: px(375);
        order: 6;
    }
}

.box6 {
    @include laptop-and-larger {
        flex-basis: 60%;
        order: 5;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that content in Box3 and Box4 has dynamic height (how to predict it actually), so sometimes it could look like:
[image]

If it is not possible to make it via **flexbox**, maybe do you know how to solve that in other way? Please about help so much!

Comment: I would solve it with CSS-Grid. Espacieally with that markup it is an easier way to solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS-only masonry layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout)

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox solution**

With Flexbox you should maintain the default `flex-direction: row` for desktop layout. Simply set the card elements to 50% width. Then set the flexbox back to row and add `flex-wrap: wrap` to allow the elements to wrap.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { 
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  section {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  /* changes the order for the 3rd and 4th element while keeping the normal order at the 5th element upwards */
  section:nth-child(-n + 2) { order: 1; }
  section:nth-child(3) { order: 3; }
  section:nth-child(4) { order: 2; }
  section:nth-child(n + 5) { order: 4; }
  
  .large {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>1</section>
  <section>2</section>
  <section class="large">3</section>
  <section class="large">4</section>
  <section>5</section>
  <section>6</section>
</div>
```

**Grid solution**

Overall CSS-Grid would be easier to achieve the layout by simply swapping from a 1-column grid to a 2-column grid. Then simply place the 3rd card element to the 2nd column by using `grid-column: 2/3`. 
Then you can correct the auto-placement of the cards by using `grid-auto-flow: row dense`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { 
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
}

section {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  }
  
  section:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
  }
  
  .large {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>1</section>
  <section>2</section>
  <section class="large">3</section>
  <section class="large">4</section>
  <section>5</section>
  <section>6</section>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree that CSS grid simplify my solution, but it does not solve a problem. The problem is that both grid and flexbox does not allow to have different height of Box3 and Box4. Please look at the second image that I attached. I can't handle it.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted... You said: *This is how it should look.* Then have a look into a masonry layout